# Iterator on generics with 'extends'

Tags: java, generics, iterator

```
public class abc<X extends Z> implements Iterable<X>
{
    protected ArrayList<X> list;

    public Iterator<X> iterator()
    {
        return list.iterator();
    }
}
```

I get a 'cannot find symbol' error for the iterator method. I have honestly no clue why.

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Please provide more context information

Comment: I have no clue either. Do you have your own ArrayList class shadowing the core class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should give the exact error message, but my guess is that you need to import the `Iterator` class (`java.util.Iterator`).

Also the way you have declared `X` requires that you have some other class named `Z` (`X` is restricted to `Z` or subclasses of `Z`).  Is this true?  If it is, you should rename it as only type parameters should have single-character names.  If it's not true, and you are considering `Z` another type parameter, you would need to declare `Z` as a type parameter somewhere.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause an "Iterator cannot be resolved to type" error?

Comment: Actually you're 100% right. I was so certain this class that I didn't need to import this class!

Comment: ugh! wasted time that won't come back to me